# How to break a data frame in R into 30 mins buckets

Tags: r

I have dataframe containing time in the format of 2014-01-31 15:33:50 for the whole day.

I'm trying to write a logic which breaks down the whole day into 30 mins buckets, so that i can run some statistical tests.

Can you please suggest me how it can be done through R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like:

```
start <- as.POSIXct("2012-01-15")
end <- start + as.difftime(1, units="mins")
Time.DF <- data.frame(Time = seq(from=start, by=15, to=end),
                      Info = 1:5)
# This is one way to do it
Time.DF$Bins <- with(Time.DF, {cut(
  Time, breaks = seq(from=min(Time), by=30, to=max(Time + 30)), labels = F)})
#                     Time Info Bins
# 1 2012-01-15 00:00:00    1    1
# 2 2012-01-15 00:00:15    2    1
# 3 2012-01-15 00:00:30    3    2
# 4 2012-01-15 00:00:45    4    2
# 5 2012-01-15 00:01:00    5    3

# This is a second way to do it
Time.DF$Bins2 <- with(Time.DF, {as.numeric(cut(
  Time, breaks = seq(from=min(Time), by=30, to=max(Time + 30))))})
#                     Time Info Bins Bins2
# 1 2012-01-15 00:00:00    1    1     1
# 2 2012-01-15 00:00:15    2    1     1
# 3 2012-01-15 00:00:30    3    2     2
# 4 2012-01-15 00:00:45    4    2     2
# 5 2012-01-15 00:01:00    5    3     3
```

Comment: Thanks for replying Jack, i basically want the bins to be numbered as 1,2,3 based on the 30 mins.

Comment: @user40465 R giggles with delight when you make such a request. I have shown 2 different ways to accomplish this, posted above.

Comment: Thanks Jack for helping me out.